# selenium and python click element in a dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, select, xpath, drop-down-menu

still new to selenium, xpath works great most of time , but not with the drop down in this case, of selecting a element from a drop down box:

the xpath of the box is:

```
//*[@id="select2-report_object-container"]
```

I get the browser to click it, now it shows a dropdown  of options, 
now I want to select the element "title" APP 7.08  from the list.

xpath wont work , as it just shows the container

```
//*[@id="select2-report_object-container"]
```

element to be selected is as follows:

```
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-report_object-container" title="APP 7.08">APP 7.08</span>
```

tag name wont work,  link  name  either , also tried with id and then the title value

Message:

> no such element: Unable to locate element

I also tried

```
selenium.select('//*[@id="select2-report_object-container"]' , title="APP 7.08";
```

no luck .

I feel like I need to add a second argument to the initial xpath or ID  but not sure what to use to call the value of  APP 7.08  from the span.

```
 <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-report_object-container" title="APP 7.08">APP 7.08</span>
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you please share html code? for select tag you can use getIndex(), getValue,getText method to get your value

Comment: this is available:   in the html for the location class,  value 17 is what I need.  <select name="location" class="report-option-select" id="report_object">
<optgroup label="Locations">
<option data-type="location" data-is-online="1" value="1"> Location 1</option>
<option data-type="location" data-is-online="1" value="11">Location 2</option>
<option data-type="location" data-is-online="1" value="17">APP 7.08</option>

</optgroup>

Comment: also image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8vdi78yfh6aqfzr/title%20app.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know which option you are going to select, so you can use visible text or value to get it done.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('select2-report_object-container'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('title')

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('title')
```

Comment: <select name="location" class="report-option-select" id="report_object">
<optgroup label="Locations">
<option data-type="location" data-is-online="1" value="1"> Location 1</option>
<option data-type="location" data-is-online="1" value="11">Location 2</option>
<option data-type="location" data-is-online="1" value="17">APP 7.08</option>

</optgroup>

Comment: the above didnt work. also I think you meant to type  selenium.select_by_visible_text('APP 7.08')     I tried      driver.find_element_by_id('select2-report_object-container').click()
selenium.select_by_visible_text('APP 7.08')                but no luck

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Did you try select ? why is it selenium.select_by_visible_text ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :-

```
 select= select(driver.find_element_by_name('location')) 
    select.select_by_value(17) or
 select.select_by_visible_text('APP 7.08')
```